# How does "transpose-sentences" work?

Tags: text-editing, sentences

How does `M-x` `transpose-sentences` work? I tested it by executing the command with point at various places (as indicated) in the following:

```
this is sentence 1. this is sentence 2. this is sentence 3.
^       ^        ^^^^       ^        ^^^^       ^        ^^
```

It either appears to do nothing, or returns "Don't have two things to transpose".

Comment: Try separating sentences with two spaces to make it work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How the function works will depend on your configuration. As a default, Emacs expects two spaces after a sentence. You can change this to one space by setting the variable `sentence-end-double-space` to `nil`. Once you've done that, it'll work as you expect.